# Constant RMSE margin between training and teseting set

Tags: logistic, cross-validation, rms, accuracy

I have a large number of independent datasets of varying size but same feature meaning. Features and outcome are both binary.
I am trying to fit logistic regression to the data.
I estimate regularization parameters with 10-fold random data partitioning (with classes proportion same as in training/testing) and select the best model based on accuracy.

When I look at the results, I see that the margin between train and test accuracy decreases with the increase of the training set size, while the SD of accuracy in different folds decreases - as expected.

[image]
[image]

However, when I look at the same plots for RMSE, the margin keeps constant regardless of the dataset size. Why could that be happening?

[image]
[image]

In the histograms below we can also see that accuracy difference is centered around 0, while rmse difference is not.

[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Bear in mind that each observation & prediction is binary, & their match / mismatch is a Bernoulli. So the variance / SD is a function of the mean.

Comment: Taken into account. So since these plots may be not representative, I added two more histograms, which just report difference between Test and Train Accuracies and RMSE, not as a function of the training set size. That deals with the problem you mentioned, right?
And the same problem is reflected in hists as well.